# Snowflake V8 engine version

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Searching the docs, I found https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/jsudflibrary:

This article states that Snowflake uses the open source V8 engine. Since the V8 engine is versioned every few months, **how do you determine the version of the V8 engine running in your Snowflake instance**?

Comment: I would suggest raising a ticket with snowflake support.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to automatically introspect this as of now, but if you'd like to tell without waiting on support, you can use the Chrome version history [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome_version_history) and [ES Compatibility Table](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/esnext/) to find test cases to run that will tell you, e.g. —

```
class C {
  #x() { return 42; }
  x() {
    return this.#x();
  }
}
return new C().x() === 42;
```

Will differentiate v8 8.3 from 8.4.